# Can I get alerts from Azure Devops in Slack?

Tags: azure-devops, slack

When someone @'s another person in a work item, is there a way to setup an alert system in a Slack channel to let that person know they have been @'d in a work item comment?

The notifications page (/_usersSettings/notifications) in azure sends out emails but we tend to be much more Slack dependent internally than email dependent for communications and I know there does exist a form of azure api work-in to Slack.

Also to note, the work item notifications section says it sends emails for when a work item is assigned to you/unassigned from you, and when "a reaction" is added to a work item comment. So it doesn't seem to have a scenario for when it is someone else's work item and in a comment they @ someone else to include them into the work item conversation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the available event type on the subscription of Azure Boards App for Slack are below:

[image]

There is not an event type specifically for the **`@mention`** method.

As the workaround, you can try using the event "**`Work item commented on`**" or "**`Work item updated`**".